# Is there an easier way to add a layer over a JSON object using Golang JSON Encoding?

Tags: json, go

The out of the box JSON encoding in Go is really nice, but I need to get the output to match a certain format by adding a layer. I've figured out a way, but  was hoping that there would be an easier way than the way I'm doing it.

Below is an example of how I'm doing it.

```
import (
  "bytes"
  "encoding/json"
  "encoding/xml"
  "fmt"
)
type Query struct {
    XMLName xml.Name      `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search query" json:"-"`
    Format  int           `xml:"-" json:"-"`
    Queries []interface{} `xml:",any" json:"queries"`
}
type TermQuery struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search term-query" json:"-"`
    Terms   []string `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search text" json:"text"`
    Weight  float64  `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search weight,omitempty" json:"weight,omitempty"`
}
// use fakeQuery to avoid an infinite loop
type fakeQuery Query

//MarshalJSON for Query struct in a special way to add wraping {"query":...}
func (q Query) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return wrapJSON(`query`, fakeQuery(q))
}
// use fakeTermQuery to avoid an infinite loop
type fakeTermQuery TermQuery

//MarshalJSON for TermQuery struct in a special way to add wraping {"term-query":...}
func (q TermQuery) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return wrapJSON(`term-query`, fakeTermQuery(q))
}

func wrapJSON(name string, item interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    b, err := json.Marshal(item)
    buffer.Write([]byte(`{"`))
    buffer.Write([]byte(name))
    buffer.Write([]byte(`":`))
    buffer.Write(b)
    buffer.Write([]byte(`}`))
    return buffer.Bytes(), err
}
```

I have a lot of defined structures that I would need to do this to, so I'm hoping for a better solution that won't leave me with with 100+ lines of code to just add a wrapper around the JSON object. Ideally I would like something that could peak at the XML element name defined for the XML encoder and use that to wrap the JSON.

In my case I'm using the MarshalJSON functions because these structures can be nested. If it helps I always know that the Query structure is the root structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I started to use Go & Json I had the same problem. I resolved it by that

```
func wrapJSON(name string, item interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    wrapped := map[string]interface{}{
       name: item,
    }
    converted, err := json.Marshal(wrapped)
    return converted
}
```

Ideally, rename your method `wrapJSON` to `wrap` that return an interface and after convert this interface to JSON or XML

Comment: Thanks. That is cleaner than what I have in my function. I was hoping for a solution that would help with nested items, though. That is why I was using the MarshalJSON functions, since TermQuery could be the one of the Queries of the Query structure.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the number of arguments to return is wrong. And, this function will cause an infinite loop: `(q Query) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)` -> `wrapJSON` -> `(q Query) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am missing something, but is this what you are looking for?

I started off with the same idea as @Manawasp (using a map[string]interface{}) but decided to try to get the name from the struct tag like you asked about... here's what I came up with (*note: there may be unhandled error cases, and this may overcomplicate something that can be handled pretty easily with the other solution)

http://play.golang.org/p/qO6tDZjtXA

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
)

type Query struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search query" json:"-"`
    Field1  string
    Field2  int64
}

type TermQuery struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search term-query" json:"-"`
    Field3  string
    Field4  int64
}

func getXmlName(d interface{}, label string) (string, bool) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(d).Kind() {
    case reflect.Struct:
        v, _ := reflect.TypeOf(d).FieldByName(label)
        parts := strings.Split(v.Tag.Get("xml"), " ")
        return parts[1], true
    }
    return "", false
}

func wrapJson(item interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    if n, ok := getXmlName(item, "XMLName"); ok {
        b, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{n: item})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return b, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("You failed")
}

func main() {
    // create a Query and encode it as {"query": {struct}}
    q := Query{Field1: "hello", Field2: 42}
    wrappedQ, err := wrapJson(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(wrappedQ))

    // create a TermQuery and encode it as {"term-query": {struct}}
    tq := TermQuery{Field3: "world", Field4: 99}
    wrappedTQ, err := wrapJson(tq)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(wrappedTQ))

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"query":{"Field1":"hello","Field2":42}}
{"term-query":{"Field3":"world","Field4":99}}
```

**EDIT**
Ok, here is an update now that I can see what your issue is.  It might be ugly, and it might not be bullet-proof (error handling, etc)... but for my test it seems to do what you want.

http://play.golang.org/p/8MloLP3X4H

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)
import (
    //"encoding/json"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
)

type Query struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search query" json:"-"`
    Field1  string
    Field2  int64
    Queries []interface{} `xml:",any" json:"queries"`
}

type TermQuery struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search term-query" json:"-"`
    Field3  string
    Field4  int64
}

func getXmlName(d interface{}, label string) (string, bool) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(d).Kind() {
    case reflect.Struct:
        v, _ := reflect.TypeOf(d).FieldByName(label)
        parts := strings.Split(v.Tag.Get("xml"), " ")
        return parts[1], true
    default:
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(d).Kind())
    }
    return "", false
}

func wrapJson(item interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    if n, ok := getXmlName(item, "XMLName"); ok {

        if k := reflect.ValueOf(item).FieldByName("Queries"); k.IsValid() {
            for i := 0; i < k.Len(); i++ {
                b, err1 := wrapJson(k.Index(i).Interface())
                if err1 != nil {

                    continue
                }
                k.Index(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(b))

            }

        }
        return map[string]interface{}{n: item}, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("You failed")
}

func asJson(i interface{}) []byte {
    b, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte(`{"error": "too bad"}`)
    }
    return b
}

func main() {

    // create a TermQuery and encode it as {"term-query": {struct}}
    tq := TermQuery{Field3: "world", Field4: 99}
    wrappedTQ, err := wrapJson(tq)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(asJson(wrappedTQ)))

    // create a Query and encode it as {"query": {struct}}
    q := Query{
        Field1: "hello", 
        Field2: 42, 
        Queries: []interface{}{
            TermQuery{Field3: "world", Field4: 99},
            TermQuery{Field3: "yay, it works!", Field4: 666},
            Query{
                Field1: "Hi",
                Field2: 21,
                Queries: []interface{}{
                    TermQuery{
                        Field3: "omg",
                        Field4: 1,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    wrappedQ, err := wrapJson(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(asJson(wrappedQ)))

}
```

**PRETTY-PRINTED OUTOUT**

```
{
    "query": {
        "Field1": "hello",
        "Field2": 42,
        "queries": [
            {
                "term-query": {
                    "Field3": "world",
                    "Field4": 99
                }
            },
            {
                "term-query": {
                    "Field3": "yay, it works!",
                    "Field4": 666
                }
            },
            {
                "query": {
                    "Field1": "Hi",
                    "Field2": 21,
                    "queries": [
                        {
                            "term-query": {
                                "Field3": "omg",
                                "Field4": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close. Unfortunately I have the situations these structures being nested. So an example output is  `{"query":{"queries":[{"term-query":{"text":["data"]}}]}}`. That is why I make use of the MarshalJSON functions.

Comment: @justdewit See revised answer.  Let me know if this addresses your original question more accurately.

Comment: Thank you! Much better than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your JSON Marshaler you can define one more more (anonymous) structs with the various JSON tags and add the desired wrapping.

Since you have already defined the JSON Marshaler any tags defined in the original struct might be overriden by your JSON Marshaler implementation.

See [Golang Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/USq3NpMoTX_n).

```golang
type Book struct {
    Title     string
    Author    string
    Language  string
    Publisher string
}

func (b Book) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type BookDetailJSON struct {
        Name      string `json:"Title"`
        Author    string
        Language  string `json:",omitempty"`
        Publisher string `json:"-"`
    }
    type BookJSON struct {
        Book BookDetailJSON `json:"Novel"`
    }

    return json.Marshal(BookJSON{BookDetailJSON{
        Name:      b.Title,
        Author:    b.Author,
        Language:  b.Language,
        Publisher: b.Publisher,
    }})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
type MultiMatch struct {
    Query              string   `json:"query"`
    Fields             []string `json:"fields"`
}

func (m *MultiMatch) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    w := map[string]interface{}{}
    w["multi_match"] = *m
    return json.Marshal(w)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't match https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshaler, it should be `func (m MultiMatch) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)`. However, this function will stlil cause an infinite loop.